# Keep certain keys of a hash-map

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

What would be a quick way to keep only certain keys from a hash-map?

```
(def m {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4})
```

explicit version:

```
((fn [{:keys [b c]}] {:b b :c c})
 m)
;= {:b 2, :c 3}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`select-keys`:

```
(select-keys m [:b :c])
```